# Toggle event working sporadically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, click

Problem is that the toggle does not work with a single click.  It works when I make multiple clicks but the behavior seems to be random.  I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#mark-btn').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
         type: 'PUT',
         url:'<%= mark_exam_question_path(params[:exam_id], params[:id])%>'
       }).done(function(msg){

           $("#mark-btn").val("Marked");
           $("#mark-btn").attr("id",'unmark-btn' )
           return false        
   });

  $("#unmark-btn").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'PUT',
       url:'<%= unmark_exam_question_path(params[:exam_id], params[:id])%>'
       }).done(function(msg){

     $("#unmark-btn").val("Mark");
     $("#unmark-btn").attr("id",'mark-btn' ); 
        return false
     });
   });
  });

});
```

Comment: You are changing ids dynamically (really bad). Use the deferred syntax of `on` (using a selector), attached to the document or body, rather than `click`. You should use a class or other attribute rather than the id for state changes.

Comment: HTML code would help, or better yet, a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be changing ids dynamically, but to get it to work as-is use the deferred syntax of `on` using a selector.

This works by attaching to an element that will stick around, catch the click event, and filter the target *at the time of the click*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#mark-btn', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '<%= mark_exam_question_path(params[:exam_id], params[:id])%>'
        }).done(function (msg) {

            $("#mark-btn").val("Marked");
            $("#mark-btn").attr("id", 'unmark-btn')
            return false
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#unmark-btn", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '<%= unmark_exam_question_path(params[:exam_id], params[:id])%>'
        }).done(function (msg) {

            $("#unmark-btn").val("Mark");
            $("#unmark-btn").attr("id", 'mark-btn');
            return false
        });
    });
});
```

You should change a class or other attribute instead of the id.

Note the preferred way of doing JQuery "ready" is now just `$(function(){...});` not `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

*Note, as Arun P Johny pointed out the nesting is also incorrect. I have removed that error here too and will upvote him for that.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation as you are using dynamic id to distinguish the handler to be executed.

Also you should not register a event handler inside another one if it can be called multiple times

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '#mark-btn', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '<%= mark_exam_question_path(params[:exam_id], params[:id])%>'
        }).done(function (msg) {

            $("#mark-btn").val("Marked");
            $("#mark-btn").attr("id", 'unmark-btn')
            return false
        });

    });

    $(document).on('click', "#unmark-btn", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '<%= unmark_exam_question_path(params[:exam_id], params[:id])%>'
        }).done(function (msg) {

            $("#unmark-btn").val("Mark");
            $("#unmark-btn").attr("id", 'mark-btn');
            return false
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "you should not register a event handler inside another one if it can be called multiple times" ?

Comment: in your code the `#unmark-btn` click handler is registered with in the `#mark-btn` handler... so let take a case where the `mark-btn` is clicked then `unmark` then `mark` again... now there is two click handlers registered to the `unmark` button causing two ajax request to be sent when the `unmark` is clicked again

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie look at the formatted code http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h7WbB/1/ the second click is registered within the first click handler

Comment: Ah crud... darn formatting hid that. +1 for spotting that extra problem. Have altered answer to incorporate that as well and upvoted you for it.

Comment: @eNddy see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wa98x/1/ if you click the button multiple times and look at the console you can see... and the fix http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wa98x/2/

Answer (score 0):

On this line 
    $("#mark-btn").attr("id",'unmark-btn' )

Try adding a colon ; at the end. and on the end of your return false statements.

Comment: True for consistency, but often not required on the last statement inside a block. The problem is the event hookup to elements that don't exist yet.